# Factory is not a function in my controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to write a factory and use it in one of my controllers, but it gives me an error:

> TypeError: wordsToTrain is not a function

I made my controller and factory very simple but still don`t get why is this happening:

```
angular.module('bananaApp')
  .controller('TrainingCtrl', [ '$scope', 'wordsToTrain', function ($scope, wordsToTrain) {
    wordsToTrain();
  }]);

angular.module('bananaApp')
  .factory('wordsToTrain', function () {
    return  3;
  });
```

Comment: In your controller wordsToTrain will be equal to 3, that's how angular DI works

Comment: Here is what looks like good tutorial on AngularJS DI: http://henriquat.re/basics-of-angular/services-dependency-injection/services-and-dependency-injection-in-angularjs.html

Comment: You should probably read AngularJS' Developer's Guide [Services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) and [DI](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

Comment: @csharpfolk, you are right it`s equal to 3. I probably should return a function. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to instantiate a value. Your factory doesn't return a function it returns a value instead.

```
angular.module('bananaApp')
  .controller('TrainingCtrl', [ '$scope', 'wordsToTrain', function ($scope, wordsToTrain) {
    console.log(wordsToTrain) //this would give you 3 not a function;
  }]);

angular.module('bananaApp')
  .factory('wordsToTrain', function () {
    return  3;
  });
```

// to return a function

```
angular.module('bananaApp')
  .controller('TrainingCtrl', [ '$scope', 'wordsToTrain', function ($scope, wordsToTrain) {
    console.log(wordsToTrain()) // this would give you 3 as well but this is a function;
  }]);

angular.module('bananaApp')
  .factory('wordsToTrain', function () {
    return function() {
       return 3;
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try defining your service like this :

```
angular.module('bananaApp')
  .factory('wordsToTrain', function () {

   var wordsToTrain = {};

   wordsToTrain.getValue = function() {
      return 3;
   }
   return wordsToTrain;
  });
```

And use it like this :

```
var value=wordsToTrain.getValue();
```

Comment: You are missing return wordsToTrain in your factory function

Answer (score 0):

`Factor` will return an an object & you can attach a method to this factory function.

Beside note `[]` in angular.module.

The [] parameter in the module definition can be used to define dependent modules. Without the `[]` parameter, you are not creating a new module, but retrieving an existing one.

```
angular.module('bananaApp',[])
      .controller('TrainingCtrl', [ '$scope', 'wordsToTrain', 
                  function ($scope, wordsToTrain) {
       console.log(wordsToTrain.three());
      }]);

    angular.module('bananaApp').factory('wordsToTrain', function () {

       var _factory ={};
       _factory.three = function(){
         return 3;
           }
        return  _factory;
      });
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tmcwxe8p/) here